# How can I access a jQueryUI slider via a script injected by my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

I've made a chrome extension that adds keyboard controls to [Earbits radio](http://www.earbits.com/)

I'm trying to make the mouse wheel change the volume. I've successfully bound the mouse wheel event, but I can't access the `.slider()` property in the volume slider selector (I get `undefined is not a function`). The weird part is that I can access it fine from the developer console on the webpage.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Earbits Keyboard Controls",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Adds basic keyboard controls to Earbits radio",

    "permissions": [
        "http://www.earbits.com/*"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://www.earbits.com/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "jquery.mousewheel.js", "jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js", "controls.js"]
    }],

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And the relevant bits of my main script (the reason I put the bind in an interval is that I thought I can't access the property because it loaded lazily):

```
var options = {
    keys: {
        SPACE: 32,
        LEFT: 37,
        RIGHT: 39,
        F: 70
    },
    volumeIncrement: 5
} 

function setVolume(value) {
    var volSlider = $('.volume-slider');

    volSlider.slider('value', value);
    volSlider.slider('option', 'slide')(null, {value: volSlider.slider('value')});
}

function adjustVolume(delta) {
    var volSlider = $('.volume-slider');
    console.log(volSlider.slider('value'));
    var value = Math.min(Math.max(volSlider.slider('value') + delta, 0), 100);;

    setVolume(value);
}

$(window).load(function() {  
    var bindVolumeInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if(typeof $('.volume-slider').slider != 'undefined') {
            $('#menu, #audio-controls').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // console.log(e);
                if(parseInt(e.deltaY) > 0) {
                    adjustVolume(options.volumeIncrement);
                } else {
                    adjustVolume(-options.volumeIncrement);
                }
            });
            clearInterval(bindVolumeInterval);
            console.log('volume-bind ok');
        } else {
            console.log('volume-bind fail');
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Where are you initializing the slider actually..?

Comment: I'm not. There is a slider already initialized inside the page, and I'm trying to access it via injected js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment):

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated
>   world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into,
>   but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page.
>   It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript
>   executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse:
>   JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any
>   variables defined by content scripts.

This is actually a security feature, this way JavaScript code of the webpage cannot mess up the functionality of your extension, e.g. by redefining standard DOM methods. Your content script simply doesn't see any properties added/overridden by the JavaScript running in the web page.

Of course, this makes calling a function in the page's JavaScript code more complicated. Your content script actually loads its own copy of jQuery - but that copy knows nothing about what the web page did and consequently it also doesn't know that the element in question is a slider. [Communicating with the embedding page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication) doesn't help either because you don't control the webpage in that case.

The most robust way to run JavaScript code that can talk to the page's JavaScript appears to be adding a `<script>` tag:

```
function setVolume(value)
{
  // Sanitize parameter, to make sure it doesn't need any escaping
  value = parseInt(value, 10);

  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.async = false;
  script.textContent = "(function() {" +
      "var value = " + value + ";" +
      "var volSlider = $('.volume-slider');" +
      "volSlider.slider('value', value);" +
      "volSlider.slider('option', 'slide')(null, {value: volSlider.slider('value')});" +
    "})()";
  document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
  document.documentElement.removeChild(script);
}
```

This is a rather ugly approach, especially for lengthy scripts - you have to put the entire script into a string. So if the logic you inject into the web page gets any more complicated you might want to consider adding a script file for it to the extension. You will have to add this file to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and use its URL as script source. You will no longer be able to pass parameters in by changing the source, but you can post messages as outlined under [Communication with the embedding page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication) instead (this is a better approach anyway).

Note that an async script can be added to the page and immediately removed, it already executed by then. Note also that you don't need jQuery in the content script - all jQuery calls happen in the web page and that one already has jQuery loaded.

Comment: Just wanted to ask, why won't message passing between scripts help in this case.

Comment: @ParagGangil: Between what scripts? If you want to send a message to scripts running on the webpage - nobody is listening there. If you want to communicate between the content script and the script you injected - sure, you can use message passing then. I already added a remark on that.